# How to lookup EJB into WildFly server to a client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi, wildfly

I would like to know how to look up a EJB located into a WildFly server from a remote client using JNDI.

Here is what I use to initialize the context

```
jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://192.168.0.15:8080");
jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
Context ctx = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
```

And this is the console output when I deploy the server:

```
21:08:29,352 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-10) JNDI bindings for session bean named DataBaseServiceImpl in deployment unit deployment "AnalyseExcelServeur.war" are as follows:

java:global/AnalyseExcelServeur/DataBaseServiceImpl!serveur.database.DataBaseService
java:app/AnalyseExcelServeur/DataBaseServiceImpl!serveur.database.DataBaseService
java:module/DataBaseServiceImpl!serveur.database.DataBaseService
java:jboss/exported/AnalyseExcelServeur/DataBaseServiceImpl!serveur.database.DataBaseService
java:global/AnalyseExcelServeur/DataBaseServiceImpl
java:app/AnalyseExcelServeur/DataBaseServiceImpl
java:module/DataBaseServiceImpl
```

I have try a lot of combination but every time I get a javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: exported/AnalyseExcelServeur/DataBaseServiceImpl!serveur.database.DataBaseService -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.exported.AnalyseExcelServeur."DataBaseServiceImpl!serveur.database.DataBaseService"
at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:104)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:202)
at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have not defined an app name nor a module name.

- The project name of the server is : AnalyseExcelServeur
- The name of the EJB is DataBaseServiceImpl
- The EJB implements DataBaseService which is located in the package serveur.database

Here is how I declare the EJB:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(DataBaseService.class)
public class DataBaseServiceImpl extends SessionDB implements DataBaseService
```

On the client side the implementation of the  DataBaseService interface is located in the package compte.remote.ejb

I don't know if I have to use ejb:/appname/modulename/bean/location
or just /appname/modulename/bean/location or anything else...

Maybe I have to put a file into the .war to declare the EJB...

Comment: Did you add the Application user in jboss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it !! The problem was that i used two different classpath for the ejb.

The ejb on server side was in serveur.database.DataBaseService

The interface of the ejb on client side was in compte.remote.ejb.DataBaseService

They should be in the same path so i relocate the ejb on client side into a package name serveur.database and that work !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at the documentation :

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI

Comment: Yes, already did , i had a javax.naming.NoInitialContextException using 
`jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,"org.jboss.ejb.client.naming")`
i put the jboss-ejb-client.properties into src/main/resources (maybe it should not be here ?).

That why i used
`jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");`
Which work by the way (i have a "Handshake" and the server side react) but the ejb url is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might help to sort it out. (It's for looking up JMS queue but the same way you can do it for Beans also.)

http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/how-to-code-a-remote-jms-client-for-wildfly-8

Thanks